# How to get every array element of this json decoded array

Tags: php, arrays, json, ajax

With this php code:

```
$ajaxData = json_encode($_POST['data']);

$jsonDecode = json_decode($ajaxData, true);
var_dump($jsonDecode);
```

I get this array:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(8) "2_page-1"
    ["x"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["y"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["width"]=>
    string(2) "12"
    ["height"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
}
```

How do I get each array element (as a string) so I can use it to put it in database rows?

Comment: what do you want to get and insert into the database? Make a little example of row that you want to build please

Comment: you can always `serialize($_POST['data'])` and insert the serealized data into database and extract the value from database and `unserialize($db_value)` and use the values as you please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an array inside an array (at the position of 0).
Use a 'for' loop over the first element of the array :

```
for($i = 0;$i<count($jsonDecode[0]);$i++){
    $text = $jsonDecode[0][$i];
}
```

> '$text' contains the string of each element.

This id of course if the output of your json_decode will always return this same syntax : an array inside the first element of an array.

(In my opinion you should change your '$ajaxData' structure - there is no need for that array of only one element - put the data in side one array.

Comment: This wasn't completely what I was searching for, altough you got me onto the right track. In the end I could use a `foreach` loop